# Weird Across Class Method Calling

Tags: c#, discord

Basically, I'm developing an application based on an open source project, and I ran into a bit of a wall. I'm basically trying to get `SendText()` to send text, but I find it is extremely delayed. I did some further testing, and found out it is not the `SendText()` method itself. Here is my code for the discord command:

> ```
>     [Command("test")]
>     public async Task TestAsync()
>     {
>         ChatBots.DiscToGame.test = true;
>     }
> ```

And this is my code for the class with the `SendText()` method in it.

```
public class DiscToGame : ChatBot
{
    public static bool test;

    public override void GetText(string text)
    {
        text = GetVerbatim(text);

        if (test == true)
        {
            test = false;
            SendText("Test123");
        }
```

Comment: How does `GetText()` get called? What do you mean "delayed?" Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: My terminology is probably wrong, but `GetText()` is method from the original application where it goes through a console output of game chat line by line.

What I mean by delayed is there is a 10-20 second delay of the action being completed.

Comment: OP, I appreciate your response, but it is frustrating. Please take a moment and consider how much more familiar you are with the context than your readers. We don't know what the "original application" is or what "the action" is and I still don't know what "completed" means. If you can, describe the problem with code, or at least with unambiguous terms.